# swift - JSON dictionary parsing

Tags: json, swift

I have a JSON file like below, I want to parse it and populate my tableview.

What I want to get is "material", "categories", "product_types"

```
["facets": {
      "material" : {
        "data" : [
          {
            "count" : 3,
            "value" : "95% Polyester, 5% Spandex"
          },
          {
            "count" : 1,
            "value" : "%100 Modal"
          }
        ],
      },
      "categories" : {
        "data" : [
          {
            "id" : "7",
            "name" : "test"
          }
        ],
      },
      "product_types" : {
        "data" : [
          {
            "count" : 3,
            "value" : "Sweatshirt"
          },
          {
            "count" : 1,
            "value" : "Babet"
          }, 
        ],
      }
    }]
```

My code is:

```
var list: [String:JSON]? = [:]
func loadList(){
ModafiliAPI.sharedInstance.refine(callback: { (refineList) in
            if let data = refineList["facets"].dictionaryValue as [String:JSON]?{
                self.list = data
                self.RefineTableView!.reloadData()
                print(self.refineList!)
            }
        })
}
```

I observe that I can access "facets" from the print output. But in cellforrowat

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RefineCell") as! RefineTableViewCell
        cell.refineList = self.refineList?[indexPath.row] //-->>error
        return cell
    }
```

I am getting the following error: `Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'`

UITableViewCell:

```
var refineList:[String:JSON]?{
        didSet{
            self.setupRefineList()
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should not use SwiftyJSON in the model. It's just a brilliant tool to parse JSON to *real* collection types or custom classes / structs. It generates a lot of – unnecessary – overhead to deserialize the objects in the table view data source and delegate methods. And do not declare the data source array of a concrete existing table view as optional.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode doesn't know what type is refineList, it's ambiguous for him

try

```
cell.refineList = self.refineList?[indexPath.row] as! [String:JSON]
```

You may also check what cell.refineList type ?

Also try:

```
guard let list = refineList?[indexPath.row] else {
      print ("Unexpected error !!")
      return cell
}
cell.refineList:[String:JSON] = list as! [String:JSON]
```

Comment: Updated my question with cell code. added as! [String:JSON] and I am getting the same error.

Comment: What is the type of refineList on your cell ? Can you please send your UITableViewCell code, it can be helpful.

Comment: Please check the bottom  part of my question.